# How to unbind global hotkey in X11 (X Window System / xorg)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, hotkeys

I have an application ([quicktile](http://ssokolow.com/quicktile/)) that uses Xlib to install a global hotkey via key grabbing (XGrabKey). 
However some keys are already bound by some other application:

WARNING: Failed to bind key. It may already be in use: KP_7

**How do I unbind global hotkeys manually, e.g. by using a X command line tool?**

Note: I know I can do this via the settings of the application that actually graph the keys (e.g. window manager). This is not what I need. I need a way to tell X directly.